# yadcf and fixed column filter in bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, yadcf

I'm using bootstrap datatable along with yadcf filter plugin. Filter is working fine for normal table but if i have a fixed column and if the column has select2 dropdown then its not rendered properly. First thing is, the dropdown is hidden and also values are not populated.

Thanks in advance,
Yudhir

Answer (score 0):

Currently its not possible to use yadcf with datatables fixedcolumns because there is no option to integrate with fixed columns (lack of api to bind to)

You can contact datatables author to see if there was some progress in integration with fixed columns